# Input values are not being stored in the controller (Javascript Remoting Help)?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

Forgive my incompetence...I have a visualforce "Wizard" I had working relatively well but I have had to change some key functionality to use Javascript to call a Web Service API and return some values.  I use Jquery/Javascript tofinally map these to a range of input fields on the visualforce page.  These inputs take the form:

```
<apex:outputlabel for="txtaddr1" value="Address Line 1:"/>
<apex:inputText id="txtaddr1" value="{!conAddressLine1}" styleClass="form-control" disabled="true"/>
<apex:outputlabel for="txtaddr2" value="Address Line 2:"/>
<apex:inputText id="txtaddr2" value="{!conAddressLine2}" styleClass="form-control" disabled="true"/>
<apex:outputlabel for="txtaddr3" value="Address Line 3:"/>
<apex:inputText id="txtaddr3" value="{!conAddressLine3}"  styleClass="form-control" disabled="true"/>
<apex:outputlabel for="txtaddr4" value="Address Line 4:"/>
<apex:inputText id="txtaddr4" value="{!conAddressLine4}" styleClass="form-control" disabled="true"/>
```

I simply set the value of the input fields with:

```
$('[id$=txtaddr1]').val(data[2]);
$('[id$=txtaddr2]').val(data[3]);
$('[id$=txtaddr3').val(data[4]);
$('[id$=txtaddr4]').val(data[5]);
```

And finally within my controller I have:

```
public String conAddressLine1{get;set;}
public String conAddressLine2{get;set;}
public String conAddressLine3{get;set;}
public String conAddressLine4{get;set;}
```

Some fields appear to populate and others don't, I am pretty sure I need to use Javascript Remoting to pass the values to the controller to correctly save the information to Salesforce.  Any help would be grealty appreciated, I am currently re-reading the help online but I am clearly missing some understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I was barking up the wrong tree.  My input fields were all set to disabled, once I had marked them as enabled they worked.  I expect to use readonly instead.

```
<apex:outputlabel for="txtaddr1" value="Address Line 1:"/>
<apex:inputText id="txtaddr1" value="{!conAddressLine1}" styleClass="form-control" disabled="false"/>
<apex:outputlabel for="txtaddr2" value="Address Line 2:"/>
<apex:inputText id="txtaddr2" value="{!conAddressLine2}" styleClass="form-control" disabled="false"/>
<apex:outputlabel for="txtaddr3" value="Address Line 3:"/>
<apex:inputText id="txtaddr3" value="{!conAddressLine3}"  styleClass="form-control" disabled="false"/>
<apex:outputlabel for="txtaddr4" value="Address Line 4:"/>
<apex:inputText id="txtaddr4" value="{!conAddressLine4}" styleClass="form-control" disabled="false"/>
```